# How to handle localized URL and translation with CodeIgniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization

I am starting to develop a site using CodeIgniter 3. I am new to the framework but I've got a pretty good understanding of how it works.

Anyway what I am trying to achieve is the following.

My site handles Spanish and English as locales. So for example I want to translate my URLs in the following way.

> In Spanish: /contacto
>
> In English: /contact

But from what I understand of the inner workings of the framework, I would have to make 2 controllers, Contacto.php and Contact.php and perhaps use the same view with the specific locale and display the corresponding language strings.

Is there anyway to point /contact to /contacto? Or how would you guys resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define two routes in your `routes.php` which will point to same method in your controller. More details on using routes is [Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

```
 $route['contacto'] = "contact/index";
 $route['contact'] = "contact/index";
```

and in your controller method you can check which language is selected

```
public function index() 
        {            
            $lang= $this->lang->lang();
            if ($lang == "en")
    {
     // load english contact view
    }
    if ($lang == "es")
    {
     // load spanish contact view
    }

     }
```

Comment: I found some info on that yesterday, I just wasn't sure how to handle the language part. So it would be something like:
`$info['locale']='en'; `
`$this->load->view('contact',$info);`

Comment: Also, if I use the Language class I would only need one view and pass the language as a parameter right?

Comment: Yes you can do both ways. You can create two views or either pass a variable to same view and show related content.